# Error while squeezing the current tree-listing directory in vim (netrw)

Tags: vim

The Netrw plugin has a special `<s-cr>` keybinding to "squeeze" the current directory (hence fold it). As we all know `<s-cr>` or shift-enter has troubles with terminals and it do not properly work (in my case too, it just open a file like `<cr>`). So I remap it as follows: `nmap <leader>f <s-cr>`. After pressing \f I get these errors:

[image]

Are there any solutions? Maybe there is explicit command to map (eg `:netrw-squeeze`)?

Comment: Report to the author (or check with the latest version from his [page](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW))

Comment: Already in discuss..)